# Google apps scripts: how to save active spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, save

I have an existing spreadsheet with a button. Unfortunately, if I enter new data and immediately click the button, google is slow to update, i.e. the button doesn't grab the new data unless I save it first. So, within my button, I need to save the active spreadsheet first. Essentially, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().save()`, but that's not a real function. I checked the `SpreadsheetApp` class in the google docs for a save function but didn't see one. I also looked under the `DriveApp` class thinking that I could just fetch the ID and save the file, but I don't see a save function under that class either.

This is very simple, so there's got to be something I'm missing.

Comment: You could try putting SpreadsheetApp.flush() at the beginning of your function.  That works for scripts however I don't know if it works for cell functions.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: Have you tried using Utilities.sleep(milliseconds)? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds. This will delay your script for the number of milliseconds you indicate, so it can give time for the spreadsheet to update.